# Reduce File size of PDF Created In InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, compression

I created a simple PDF file in InDesign where I placed 15 jpegs of dimensions 2480x3508 pixels of 300 dpi and included a few hyperlinks. Each page has one image. The resultant file size of the pdf with 15 pages is 7.74 mb which is huge!

Output tab looks like:

[image: Output tab]

Advanced tab looks like:

[image: Advanced tab]

On the contrary, when I create the same pdf in Photoshop (excluding hyperlinks), the resultant file size is 2.28 mb.

How can I reduce the file size in InDesign without compromising quality?

Comment: Could it be that you are embedding InDesign data into your document? Check all other tabs in the Export PDF dialog

Comment: @MaxWyss Maybe but what kind of data are you referring to? WRT the above screenshot, the Marks & bleed, Output, Advanced, Security settings are set to default.

Comment: What are the output settings? The data I refer to would be analogous to what is embedded when the "keep editable" option is set when exporting to PDF from Illustrator. (I can not verify it, as I currently do not have access to InDesign).

Comment: I've embedded a few jpegs in InDesign that I created in PS. The resultant PDF is nothing but those jpegs. Hence, I guess chances of that is nil.

Comment: Would it be possible to also show the Output and the Advanced tabs in your export settings?

Comment: Sure. I've included screenshots of Output and Advanced tabs in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for these two screenshots. I don't see anything weird. Now, if you have Acrobat at hand, try to do a Save as… --> Optimized PDF, and from that dialog run the analyze usage command. This would give you a hint about how much is used in the file (most likely, a big percentage goes to images).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick solution maybe this online reducer can help.
http://smallpdf.com/compress-pdf

Comment: True. But the question is when you have InDesign, why should you need to go to SmallPDF? :-)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for now would be to use your Photoshop PDF, then apply hyperlinks using Acrobat Pro. This is found in the edit PDF menu.

Comment: @Consumer Coffee I am not understanding your first point. As suggested, I imported & placed a .psd file inside InDesign. But when I select the image (I can't see the psd layers anymore), the Type > 'Create Outlines' option is disabled. Can you pls elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Ah sorry, I somehow miss read your question and thought they also contained text which was hyperlinked. Try adding links with acrobat pro to the photoshop PDF, that should be fine. I'm not really sure of the course for the InDesign file being bigger though. I'll edit the above answer.